# Amazon IAM for Website Authentication

Tags: web, amazon-iam

Can Amazon AWS IAM be used for user login in websites ?

Answer (score 2):

No. IAM users are for accessing/controlling AWS infrastructure as defined by a policy.

It's completely unrelated to web authentication like OpenID, OAuth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AWS IAM for this purpose.

You can use AWS Cognito instead.